# Obj-C __block variable retain behavior

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, objective-c-blocks

I'm encountering a strange issue when attempting to access a `__block` (block mutable) variable from outside of a block in which it is modified. This is a very toy example that I'm using just to get a better understanding of blocks in general, but currently I have a controller with this method that creates a string with the contents of an `NSDictionary` which uses `NSDictionary`'s `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:`

```
- (NSString*) contentsOfDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary
{
    __block NSString *content = @"";

    [dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop){
        NSString* contentToAppend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Object:%@ for key:%@\n", obj, key];
        content = [content stringByAppendingString:contentToAppend];
        NSLog(@"Content in block:\n%@", content);
    }];

    NSLog(@"Content out of block:\n%@", content);

    return content;
}
```

When I run this method with a dictionary containing the contents:

```
Value    Key
"Queen"  "card"
"Hearts" "suit"
"10"     "value"
```

The `content` variable is modified correctly within the block and I get this output with each iteration:

...Content in block:

```
Object:Queen for key:card
```

...Content in block:

```
Object:Queen for key:card
Object:Hearts for key:suit
```

...Content in block:

```
Object:Queen for key:card
Object:Hearts for key:suit
Object:10 for key:value
```

As soon as the code steps out of the block though, accessing the `content` string throws an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and on one run occasion it seems to have printed some garbage memory (can't reproduce)...

What is causing this variable to be deallocated early? I was under the impression that giving it a `__block` definition would mean that it is retained when used within a block and released when the block exits - But the variable is retained and autoreleased to start off with by virtue of being a string literal so I expect it not to be dealloced until after this method exits at the earliest.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
content = [content stringByAppendingString:contentToAppend];
```

`-stringByAppendingString:` returns a new, autoreleased object. The address of this object is stored in `content`. Each go through this (implicit) loop – that is to say, each invocation of the provided block – is creating a brand new object and then assigning the address of that new object to `content`. None of these objects outlives its containing autorelease pool.

What you should be doing is using an `NSMutableString` and directly appending the `contentToAppend` to the mutable string. For example:

```
- (NSString*) contentsOfDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary
{
    NSMutableString *content = [NSMutableString string];
    [dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:
    ^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop){
        NSString* contentToAppend = [NSString stringWithFormat:
            @"Object:%@ for key:%@\n", obj, key];
        [content appendString:contentToAppend];

        NSLog(@"Content in block:\n%@", content);
    }];

    NSLog(@"Content out of block:\n%@", content);
    return content;
}
```

Note that `__block` is no longer necessary, as you do not assign to `content` anywhere within the block.

Answer (score 5):

Internally, `-enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:` is using an autorelease pool. `__block` scoped objects are not retained past the end of the block's lifetime, so you end up with an object you created in the block's scope that is then deallocated when the dictionary's autorelease pool is drained, which all happens before you attempt to print the value of `content`.

Comment: How can I prevent the dictionary's autorelease pool from being drained? Is there something fundamentally wrong about what I'm doing?

Comment: You can't override the pool, but you can retain the object within the enumeration (make sure not to leak objects as you loop!) and then autorelease or release it outside of the loop when you're done with it.

Comment: I see, the implicitly autoreleased stringByAppendingString could be retained and released manually to avoid the issue, but I guess the MutableString makes this a lot easier. I have a feeling this won't be my last memory management related block issue though :(

Comment: donalbain, this isn't really a block issue, the `autorelease` pool is inside the `-enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock`. You can always write the method yourself, as I've done: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169546/assigning-objects-to-variable-outside-a-block/7170778#7170778), although the best thing in this exact situation is to use a `NSMutableString`.