# Assigning objects to variable outside a block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

The following code crashes, since the contents of `sentence` go away when the final block exits.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>    
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // simple block test - just iterate over some items and 
    // add them to a string
    NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"why ", @"must ", @"this ",nil];
    __block NSString *sentence = @"";   
    [items enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
    {
        sentence = [sentence stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",obj];
    }];
    // crash!
    NSLog(@"Sentence is %@",sentence);
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

What is the correct / idiomatic way to make this work?

Comment: Wow, that's bizarre, I'm not sure why that doesn't work.

Comment: I've seen people do a `[[someVariable retain] autorelease]` at the end of blocks to return things, but I'm not sure why that should make any difference if as I suspect, an autorelease pool runs. I don't know though, that's why I'm asking, and there's all kinds of articles on copying blocks, and passing them around, but nothing that I can find on something that should be simple, like this.

Comment: What is the error/exception you get?

Comment: `Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.` It faults because `sentence` has been `release'd`. I outline what I believe is happening below, and it's really not anything to do with blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I went away and played with Xcode for a bit, and here's a model of what's going on, that seems to match what I'm seeing.

The block I used above isn't doing anything special, but the `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` code appears to have its own `NSAutoreleasePool`, so that seems to be what was causing `dealloc` to be called on objects `alloc'ed`, but autoreleased inside the block.

The following code matches in behavior what I'm seeing above:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h> 
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // simple block test - just iterate over some items and 
    // add them to a string
    typedef void (^AccArrayBlock)(id obj, int idx, BOOL *stop);
    // items to 'process'
    NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"why ", @"must ", @"this ",nil];
    int idx = 0;
    BOOL doStop = NO;
    // make sentence mutable, so we can assign it inside block
    __block NSString *sentence = @"";
    // make a similar block to what we'd pass to enumerate...
    AccArrayBlock myBlock = ^(id obj, int idx, BOOL *stop)
    {
        // returns and assigns an autoreleased string object
        sentence = [sentence stringByAppendingFormat:@"(%d) %@  ",idx,obj];
    };
    // enumerate items and call block
    for (NSString *item in items) {
        // create a pool to clean up any autoreleased objects in loop
        // remove this line, and the sentence will be valid after loop
        NSAutoreleasePool *innerPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        myBlock(item, idx++, &doStop);
        // drain the pool, autorelease objects from block
        [innerPool drain];
        if (doStop) {
            break;
        }
    }
    // faults if we drained the pool
    // Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
    NSLog(@"Sentence is %@",sentence);
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

If I remove the `innerPool` object, then the code works as I originally expected, and presumably the `NSRunLoop` pool will eventually clean up the various `NSString` objects.

NOTE: This thread is now the number 2 Google result for 'enumerateObjectsUsingBlock autorelease':

[Google 'enumerateObjectsUsingBlock+autorelease'](http://www.google.com/search?q=enumerateObjectsUsingBlock+autorelease&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aunofficial&client=firefox-a)

The first result confirms this answer. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I'm not 100% sure what's going on there but in the mean time it works if you change

```
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"why ", @"must ", @"this ",nil];
NSMutableString *sentence = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];   
[items enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
{
    [sentence appendFormat:@"%@",obj];
}];

NSLog(@"Sentence is %@",sentence); 

[sentence release]; sentence = nil;
```

Updated thanks to @nacho4d

Comment: I this case I think is not needed the `__block` modifier. And do not forget to `[sentence release]` of-course :)

Comment: Thanks, I've used something like that somewhere else, but I'm trying to work out how to get objects, allocated in a block, out of a block without them going away. The code above is just the simplest thing I could think of to demonstrate something I don't understand. Of course writing code like this using `NSMutableString` is more efficient anyway, but I just wanted a simple bit of demo code. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer may lie in here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW1 but I'm too tired to make any sense of it. Maybe if you can you can answer your own question for everyones reference

Comment: Yeah, I'm wiped out myself. One thing that occurs to me is that quite a lot may be going on under the covers of `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock`. I'll try this with a custom object and confirm `dealloc` being called. The annoying thing is I had a pretty good handle on memory management pre-blocks, but this has really thrown a wrench in the works.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, I suspect this is crashing when the autorelease pool runs, as it probably does in `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`. This will be annoying to work around if you have a `__block` variable. You could use an NSMutableString instead, or simply do this, which is cleaner anyway:

```
for (id obj in items)
{
     sentence = [sentence stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",obj];
}
```

Alternatively, if you use [ARC](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html), the compiler should eliminate the problem for you.